# Text markup language that supports URL path as URL link text? (Markdown and Textile cannot?)

Tags: url, hyperlink, jekyll, markup

Using Jekyll and Github, it seems that whichever markup language I choose, MD or Textile, I cannot have the program compute the name of the link text to be the same as the link path itself. In other words, I'd like to be able to just spell out a URL and have the markup figure out it should be made into an `href`.

Is there a way to do this in either Markdown or Textile? 
Alternatively, is there another markup language that I can plug-in to my blog to get this feature?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is impossible to do that with a standard MD/textile parser. You will always have to specify the link text and it's target. 
However, you could create this functionality by modifying an existing MD/textile parser and dropping that in place of a stock parser. Obviously this can't be done on Github. 
In that case you could just write your MD/textile in any programmer's text editor and use regex substitution to find and fix the url notation.

Comment: I would use it so often it almost seems like it would be worth the work to make a new parser. Have you done that? I'm not sure where I would start, google was hard to do to find the right words to find the origin repo. Maybe another thing I should look at would be an intermediary, where I create a preprocessor and hand MD/Textile formatts they like? thank you for your thoughts!